# ComboBox data binding does not work using DataReader

Tags: c#

Some of you may think it has already been solved somewhere else in this community, but I cannot really get around of it. 
I have a ComboBox and I like it to be populated using DataReader. As usual, I have created a Class to get-set `value member` and `display member`. My code goes below.

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items WHERE status='active'", Class_Connection.conn))
        {
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList temptbl = new ArrayList();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(rdr.GetString(1).ToString() + "::" + rdr.GetString(0).ToString());
                temptbl.Add(new Class_NameValue(rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(0)));
            }
            rdr.Close();

            // define Display and Value members
            cmb_items.DisplayMember = "NameMember";
            cmb_items.ValueMember = "IdMember";
            // set the DataSource to the DataTable 
            cmb_items.DataSource = new BindingSource(temptbl, null); 
        }
```

The Get-Set Class is below:

```
class Class_NameValue
{
    private string myNameMember;
    private string myValueMember;

    public Class_NameValue(string strNameMember,string stringValueMember)
    {
        this.myNameMember = strNameMember;
        this.myValueMember = stringValueMember;


    }
    public string NameMember
    {
        get
        {
            return myNameMember;
        }
    }
    public string IdMember
    {
        get
        {
            return myValueMember;
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles ok. But when the application runs, it gives an error 
"`Cannot bind to the new display member.Parameter name: newDisplayMember`"

Whats wrong with my code? Can anybody help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the

> DisplayMember and ValueMember Properties before the DataSource.

Like

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ArrayList temptbl = new ArrayList();
while (rdr.Read()){
    temptbl.Add(new Class_NameValue(rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(0)));
}
rdr.Close();
cmb_items.DisplayMember = "NameMember";
cmb_items.ValueMember = "IdMember";
cmb_items.DataSource = new BindingSource(temptbl, null);
```

There is one more trick pass the `NameMember` and `IdMember` from

> temptbl.Add(new Class_NameValue(rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetInt32(0)));

to

> temptbl.Add(new Class_NameValue(NameMember =
>   rdr.GetString(1).ToString(), IdMember=rdr.GetString(0).ToString()));

means set the property `value` from here not in the class itself.
Please try..

Hope it works..

Comment: I tried this before. Doesn't work. But if a comment the ValueMember line, it works fine. But in that way, I do not get the value of item.

Comment: it's means that any one NameMember has no IdMember,try to run your query in sql or mysql editor for checking null IdMember value.

Comment: ok try to run your query in sql or mysql browser and check that all `IdMember` column has a notnull value or check that you `valueMember` name in query must be `"IdMember"`,,check spelling mistake..

Comment: Its not generating any error now, but showing get-set Class Name in the combobox instead of item name. But I am sure the value and name has been bind since getting them under SelectedIndex event.

Comment: The ID member seems to be good @Rahul. I show you here the updated code along with the Get-Set class.

Comment: The Question has been modified new @Rahul.

Comment: while using my latest trick not forget to remove `this.myNameMember = strNameMember;`and `this.myValueMember = stringValueMember;` from `Class_NameValue` constructor..

Comment: Nothing positive yet @Rahul. I had a bad day yesterday. Hope to solve it by this session. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var bs = new BindingSource(temptbl, null);
cmb_items.DataSource = bs;
cmb_items.DisplayMember = "yourDisplayMember";
cmb_items.ValueMember = "yourValueMember";
```

Comment: That's what i was trying to do @03Usr for long. Binding does not work while adding items with DataReader.